# Python not able to calculate a seventh polynomial equation

Tags: python, java, polynomials

I have to calculate an equation to translate coordinates in two different fields. With Geogebra I've come up whit this equations which I checked and is correct:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/StSCs.jpg <-- Link to the equation

The input and output of this equation are as follows:

| Input | Output |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 6 |
| 1 | 7 |
| 2 | 8 |
| 3 | 11 |
| 4 | 12 |
| 5 | 13 |
| 6 | 16 |
| 7 | 17 |
| 8 | 18 |

As already stated the equation is correct.

To test this equation I've implemented it into python

```py
import math
import colorful

def polynom(x):
    return 0.0036 * pow(x,7) - 0.1 * pow(x,6) + 1.1 * pow(x,5) - 6 * pow(x,4) + 16.7583 * pow(x,3) - 21.9 * pow(x,2) + 11.1381 * x + 6


# To test the equation with the input and the expected output
for i in range (0,9):
    result = polynom(i)
    if result == exp[i]:
        print(colorful.green(str(i) + " : " + str(result)))
    else:
        print(colorful.red(str(i) + " : " + str(result)))
```

Strangely this script gives me the following output:

```
0 : 6.0
1 : 7.0
2 : 8.003399999999996
3 : 11.061599999999942
4 : 12.465999999999973
5 : 15.228000000000364
6 : 23.99099999999936
7 : 40.51839999999771
8 : 77.90159999999871
```

Whereby only two are correct while the rest give increasingly odd solutions.

Now my questions:

- Is this a problem with the engine of python itself?
- Is there a typo or a thought error
- If I would implement this in Java would a similar error arise?

Comment: The image seems to be broken, isn't it?

Comment: @js-on Yes, thank you for pointing that out

Answer (score 1):

The results that python is giving you are correct. What is wrong is your table with input and expected output.

I checked the results of: `0.0036 * xˆ7 - 0.1 * xˆ6 + 1.1 * xˆ5 - 6 * xˆ4 + 16.7583 * xˆ3 - 21.9 * xˆ2 + 11.1381 * x + 6` in wolfram website: [equation result link for P(x)=8](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=0.0036%20*%208%CB%867%20-%200.1%20*%208%CB%866%20%2B%201.1%20*%208%CB%865%20-%206%20*%208%CB%864%20%2B%2016.7583%20*%208%CB%863%20-%2021.9%20*%208%CB%862%20%2B%2011.1381%20*%208%20%2B%206) and is giving me the same results as your python test does.

I think you need to recalculate your output expectations.

Answer (score 0):

Having run the equation in Excel, the results look correct.
Here is the case for x = 3

So, yes, it looks like the results you have are the expected ones.

[image]

Comment: My bad, the equation image didn't load. But this your answer tells me that I might just have a typo somemwere

Answer (score 0):

I think you've copied the equation from GeoGebra without increasing the Rounding setting. Try with 15 significant figures